# How to convert an embedded JSON string to a JSON Object in C#

Tags: c#, json, api

I have a function that returns data as a json string and I am calling that string inside my api but I want my api to return a json object instead of a json string.

This is what the function looks like:

```
   public JObject InquiryPaymentAPI(string id)
        {
           
            string paymentInfo = PaymentInquiry.IPayment(id);
            return JObject.Parse(paymentInfo);

        }
```

This returns a json object but the embedded part looks like an empty array how do I get it to return all the data please help I am new to c#

```
{
    "paymentId": [],
    "paymentRequestId": [],
    "paymentAmount": [
        [
            []
        ],
        [
            []
        ]
    ],
    "paymentStatus": [],
    "result": [
        [
            []
        ],
        [
            []
        ],
        [
            []
        ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please include the class definition of the return value of PaymentInquiry.IPayment() in your question

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am not sure if I understand do you mind elaborating?

Comment: The `IPayment` method will have a signature similar to `public Foo IPayment(string id)` (except it probably isn't called `Foo`). We need to know the definition of that `Foo` (or whatever it's called) class, because that defines the shape of the object you're trying to represent as JSON.

Comment: Is there a hard requirement that you can only move up to JObject level? If the string form is like walking to work uphill, the JObject form is like skateboarding to work uphill instead. Chauffeur driven Teslas are available by pasting your JSON into http://quicktype.io

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know the json response, you can create a model class for it. On VS 2022 you can right click on editor and do paste special `Edit --> Paste special --> Paste JSON as Classes`. You should get something like below.

```
public class Model 
{
    public object[] paymentId { get; set; }
    public object[] paymentRequestId { get; set; }
    public object[][][] paymentAmount { get; set; }
    public object[] paymentStatus { get; set; }
    public object[][][] result { get; set; }
}
```

After using that `Model` class in your code, your code should look like below

```
using System.Text.Json;

public Model InquiryPaymentAPI(string id)
{
   
    string paymentInfo = PaymentInquiry.IPayment(id);
    return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Model>(paymentInfo);

}
```